# DatePicker, как создать Ajax запрос

Tags: yii2

я создал таблицу где в колонке могу задавать дату с помощью DatePicker и мне необходимо, чтобы дата которую я выбрал сохранялась в БД, но я не знаю как это сделать. Вот DatePicker в View

```
 [
    'label' => 'Дата подписки',
    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
        return  DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'value' => $model->date_subscription,
        'attribute' => 'date_subscription',
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
        'pluginOptions' => [
             'autoclose'=>true,
             'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
]
        ]);
    },
    'format' => 'raw'
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

А если у вас вся таблица отправляется уже через AJAX, то в модели в таблице должно быть добавлено поле с вашей датой. И попробуйте задать 'name' => 'date_subscription', если у вас такое имя в модели.

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня в таблице значения не отправляются кроме одного, с кнопкой значение. Вот после GridView идет её код
        $(".user_subscription").click(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/admin/clients/subscription',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    data: this.name
                },

А как DatePicker отправлять через Ajax, я не понимаю, новичек и первый раз столкнулся

Comment: Абсолютно также и пробуйте $("SELECTOR").click(function(){ jQuery.ajax({ url: 'CONTROLLER', type: 'post', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', async: true, dataType: 'html', data: { data: INFORMATION }

Я сам новичек, но если чем-то могу помочь стараюсь помочь, даже если ошибаюсь, эта мотивация лучше.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую как доберусь

Comment: Не подскажите ещё, а в контролере надо будет прописать что-то?

Comment: в контроллере вероятнее всего нет, ему все-равно какую информацию передать, а в модели естественно должна быть валидация и поле в таблице для date_subscription

Comment: Странно, все равно не работает, хотя поле есть. Значения не меняются